# The BitLocker recovery key does not work to access the Windows partition in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

hello I have a problem when entering a partition that uses bitlocker it turns out that I put the recovery key to access the partition but I get the ERROR Unlocking /dev/sda3: Failed to activate device: Operation not supported. Before this did not happen to me but now it happens every so often when I put the recovery key.

[image: Enter the BitLocker Recovery Key]

[image: but this error comes out]

how can i solve this error?

Comment: Sporadic entry problems may be caused by keyboard state -- maybe the CapsLock or NumLock is on (NumLock may cause some letters to type numbers).  Ensure the "view" icon  (after the text fiels) is pressed to see what you are actually typing.

Comment: Problem solved I don't know how since I always put the password correctly and I got an error apparently it was an unknown error but I was able to access my partition without having to disable BitLocker